# How can I make a ViewModel for a Xamarin Forms template?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Template1 that inherits from ContentView. For the purpose of this question I removed a lot of things in the template to make it simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" x:Class="Japanese.Template1" x:Name="this">
   <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" />

</ContentView>
```

and the Template1 C# back end

```
namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class Template1 : ContentView
    {
        public CardOrderTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like this template to share bindings in this class and so I tried some different ways to do this but none seem to work.  Here's what I was trying. Not sure but I guess I need something like a ViewModel for the template but I am not sure how I could go about implementing this.

```
namespace Japanese
{
    public class SegBase : ContentView
    {

         public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(SegTemplate), default(string));
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this? I tried making the Template1 class inherit from SegBase but it gives me an error because the XAML is a type ContentView and the C# is not inheriting from ContentView.

Comment: Xamarin has templating built in. You can define page and content view templates in ResourceDictionaries. These templates are applied by setting a Page or ContentView's ControlTemplate property to the template you have defined. You can bind from a Template to the view that is using the template through a TemplateBinding, which is like Binding to the ViewModel, but instead binds to the Parent view. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating